# Java regex matcher doesnt match

Tags: java, regex

I cant understand why the result is always false

```
package test;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        String pattern = "place (//d+);(//d+);(//d+);(//d+)";

        // Create a Pattern object
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        Matcher matcher1 = r.matcher("place 66;33;65;87");

        System.out.println(matcher1.matches());

    }

}
```

Comment: Trivial typo? // -> \\

Comment: Andrey is right, change `//` (forward slash) to \\ (back slash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The escaping character in both regex and java String literals is a backslash, not a forward slash. You want to get `\d` in regex (escaped `d` for **d**igits). You have to escape it by another backslash in string literal, so you obtain `\\d`.

With

```
"place (\\d+);(\\d+);(\\d+);(\\d+)"
```

it matches and works.

---

You can of course take it sportive and try to write a regex-replacement that replaces all `//` by `\` in your regex... Something like this:

```
String pattern = "place (//d+);(//d+);(//d+);(//d+)".replaceAll("//", "\\\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        String pattern = "(place) (\\d+);(\\d+);(\\d+);(\\d+)";

        // Create a Pattern object
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

        Matcher matcher1 = r.matcher("place 66;33;65;87");

        System.out.println(matcher1.matches());
    }
```

You need to provide `place` in round braces and the slash thing.